# Unable to open up SonarQube page

Tags: mysql, linux, sonarqube, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing **SonarQube** on my Ubuntu Server with the help of [this](https://www.voyalab.com/2016/10/06/install-sonarqube-ubuntu/) link. When i start/restart Sonar from terminal it shows like this:
[image: starting SonarQube]

But when i try to open sonar page **ipaddress:9000/sonar** the page is not at all opening.

But i followed same link for installation on my ubuntu VM, it worked as expected.

after `netstat -ntl` got following output

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::36870                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::35866                :::*                    LISTEN
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/a7a418ee9e0a9ad5ef0a991a3c7fbdc5) is my sonarQube property file which i used for installation.

Following logs which i got after restarting SonarQube

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.06.06 23:14:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.06.06 23:14:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Des.network.host=127.0.0.1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process4114582605652920236properties
2017.06.06 23:15:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.06.06 23:15:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process3191822142101588969properties
2017.06.06 23:15:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.06.06 23:15:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.06.06 23:15:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Are you able to access SonarQube on the same machine where it is running? Probably yes. When you try to access SonarQube from a different machine, are you sure you are using the correct IP address?

Comment: and also i followed same steps on my local VM and all is working fine

Comment: @janos, yes am using correct IP address. Even i have installed few more apps on it and able to access those apps. But not able to access SonarQube

Comment: Can you access `ipaddress:9000` instead of `ipaddress:9000/sonar` ?

Comment: Nope tried that also but still the same result.

Comment: Thanks the `netstat -ntl` clarifies some things. Can you please add the output of the command `curl ipaddress:9000`, executed from the machine itself that runs SonarQube, and also from the other machine?

Comment: after doing curl i am getting `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused` this one. And also one more thing i observed, after restarting sonar `netstat -ntl` shows that port is listening but after some time if i execute `netstat -ntl` it doesn't show anything related to that port

Comment: To be clear: _sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1_ forces SonarQube to listen on _localhost_, preventing external access via other interfaces. I suggest you first comment that out and then observe latest behaviour/logs.

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam i commented that line and still i am not able to open and after doing `curl` still it is same

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam @janos , i just tried commenting line `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance` and it woked. I mean sonar started with embedded database. So what should be the problem now.

Comment: [SonarQube](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/af1e01d4b3e50dd5d9bbb35fef2020f0) log. I guess SonarQube is not able to connect to mysql.

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam can any one solve this for me....it will eb very helpful

Answer (score 1):

After installing `Ubuntu 16 Desktop edition` the problem got solved. I don't the specific reason why it was giving error, but after installing `Desktop` version, without changing anything it got solved.